# Javascript if arrays contains string with regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I want to found if the variable `url` matches to any value of the array
**For example, here's my array:**

```
var arr = ["test", "foo", "bar", "news-[0-999999999999999]*"];
```

**... and my string**

```
var url = "news-294";
```

I need to check for each `arr` value if it matches to url, with `regex`

So I've tried a `foreach` on the array, `new RegExp` for each value and then check if it matchs. But It didn't worked well, and It was leaking my browser memory (the `CPU` was at 24% for a blank page with the script)

How can I do that? Thanks

**EDIT: here's my code:**

```
var CMS = {
    RegexMatch: function(regex, str, callback) {
        while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
            if(m[0] == str) callback();
        }
    },
    ArrayFindRegex: function(array, str, callback) {
        array.forEach(function(e) {
            CMS.RegexMatch(new RegExp(e), str, function() {
                callback();
            });
        });
    },
        Check: function() {
                var url = "blabla";
                CMS.ArrayFindRegex(["test", "foo", "bar", "news-[0-999999999999999]*"], url, function() {
                    console.log('wow');
                });
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Add your code to the question so we can see what happened. Also, what do you want to happen if it finds a match?

Comment: execute `callback()`. Just posting my code wait

Comment: If you want to do regexp testing, why start with strings? Just store regexp: `var arr = [/test/, /foo/, /bar/, /news-\d+/];` and then do an `arr.forEach(re => re.test(...))` or `for (re of arr) { re.test(...) }` (with the benefit that the latter will let you break out of the loop, while the former won't)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  Can you make an answer please?

Comment: @MrZ, Check your curly braces. It seems you have some error in defining CMS as well.

Comment: @Mojtaba oh that's just and error when copying & past, but thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead. It's more idomatic than each (or other iteration methods, in this case). `filter` returns an array with the contents being any matches or empty if none are found.

```
var arr = ["test", "foo", "bar", "news-[0-999999999999999]*"];
var url = "news-294";

var matches = arr.filter(function(pattern) {
  return new RegExp(pattern).test(url);
})

console.log(matches);
```

The above example logs `["news-[0-999999999999999]*"]`. You can assert a positive result based off the length of `matches`.

Comment: No comment on that horrible regex itself, then?

Comment: You're right, the original code could be improved, but others seem to be offering advice on that. I simply wanted to provide a solution for what the OP currently had, not a refactor.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do regular expression matching, start with regular expressions, not strings.

```
var arr = [/test/, /foo/, /bar/, /news-\d+/];
```

Then you can do normal matching without weird string rewrites or intepretations:

```
var matched = arr.some(re => re.test(...))
if (matched) {
  doSomeThing()
}
```

or

```
for (re of arr) {
  if (re.test(...)) {
    doSomeThing();
    break;
  }
}
```